# TortoiseSVN update and cleanup remotely don't work

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, virtual-machine

I'm trying to do a cleanup and update on a working copy on a remote machine, using the following line:

svn cleanup \{machine name}\path.to.working.copy

and

svn update \{machine name}\path.to.working.copy

I get the following error:
svn: Error resolving case of '\{machine name}\path.to.working.copy

both machines are virtual and on the same domain.
pinging each other is successful.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to access it using the windows share path, then it's double-backslash `\\the-other-machine\` using either the machine's name or IP address. You also need a share name; if you have administrative access to the machine there will usually be a hidden admin share drive-name-$, i.e.

```
\\the-other-machine\c$\path.to.working.copy\
```

If that doesn't work, the best thing to do is to try opening the path in explorer which will handle authentication and connection for you. You can also use `net use` on the console, e.g.

```
net use \\the-other-machine\c$
```

If that still doesn't work you need to make sure that file sharing is enabled on the remote machine and the relevant firewall ports open, that the shares you're trying to access exist (or create a new one) and - if the machine isn't on a domain - that local security policy allows remote users to log in.

Comment: the folder on the destination machine is shared and the user has admin permissions. Opening the folder in Windows Explorer, I can do this and it's OK.
Are you saying my problem has nothing to do with SVN?

Comment: I would have thought so - I tested `svn status` against a colleague's machine and it worked fine for me. Googling for your error I've only found [references to mixed slashes in file URLs](http://www.tomred.net/svn-error-resolving-case.html) - you're not doing anything like that are you? If all the file shares work then I guess it's now down to the way APR is parsing your path and that's going wrong somewhere - sorry that wasn't any help.

Comment: I use double-backslash, it didn't write it on the question though. Thanks for your try. What is APR ?

Comment: It's Apache Portable Runtime - it's the library Subversion uses for OS abstraction, file handling etc.